# Multiple Serialport reads after reloading webpage in node.js

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I am trying to use node.js on a Raspberry Pi to interface a serial device.  I want to send data from the device to a webpage, send control data from the webpage to the device and log and store data on the Pi.
When I run this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/engComp.html'));
    }).listen(8080, function(){console.log('Listening at: http://localhost:8080');});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var serialport = require("serialport");
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var sp = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", {
    baudrate: 9600,parser: serialport.parsers.readline('\r')});

sp.open(function (){console.log('serial port open');
    io.on('connection', function (socket){
        console.log('socket open');
        socket.on('data',function(recData){   //data recieved from socket
            console.log('http rec data = '+recData);
            sp.write(recData, function(err, results){
                console.log('serial port send data = '+recData);
            });
        });
        sp.on('data', function(sdata){        //data recieved from serial port
            console.log('serial port rec sdata = ' + sdata);
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function (){
            console.log('socket disconnect');
//            sp.close(function(){
//                console.log('serial port closed');
//            });
        });
    });
});
```

and reload the page say 3 times I get 3 outputs for each serial data read.

If I put back (un-rem) the sp.close() it works until I reload as expected (the port is closed but never reopened).

If I put the sp.open() in the io.on(connection) callback and serial data comes in while the page is reloading (after sp.close() but before sp.open() it crashes with:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: EBADF, read
```

I would prefer not to close the port durring a reload as this would interfere with loging to the Pi.

I am using node v0.10.26 but same thing happens with v0.8.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operating on the assumption that you intend for there to only be one serial connection open and one website connection open, try something like this.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/engComp.html'));
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var SerialPort = require('serialport').SerialPort;
var sp = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyAMA0', {
    baudrate: 9600,
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline('\r')
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('socket open');

  socket.on('data', function(recData) {
    console.log('http rec data =', recData);
    sp.write(recData, function(err, results){
        console.log('serial port send data =', recData);
    });
  });
});

sp.open(function () {
  console.log('serial port open');

  server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Listening at: http://localhost:8080');
  })

  sp.on('data', function(sdata) {
    io.emit('sdata', sdata);
    console.log('serial port rec sdata = ', sdata);
  });
});
```

Now there is only one serial port connection opened and it doesn't open / close between requests. Furthermore, the website only starts listening for connections after the serial port has been opened and is ready for data.

Comment: I am new to node.js and may be confused about scope and callbacks.  I need to send data from the serial device to a webpage.  It looks to me like my serial data, `sdata` and `socket` are in different functions.  Can I make them global even though they are defined in a callback?  And yes, sorry, I forgot to ask the question: Why am I getting multiple open serial connections if I'm only hitting sp.open() once?

Comment: To send data from sp to webpage, you can use io.emit. I've added that example to the answer above. With the code above you're seeing multiple 'serial port open' messages?

Comment: No, I was not getting multiple 'serial port open' messages only multiple 'serial port rec sdata = ' messages.  I was using socket.emit to send data to the webpage.

Comment: Multiple 'serial port rec sdata' is normal. It should be called multiple times as the device reports more data.

Comment: I was not making myself clear.  I was getting (with my code) multiple reports for EACH serial data point.  If the serial data were: 1,2,3 when I first opened the page I would get 1,2,3 on the console. If I reloaded the page (or accessed the page from another device) I got 1,1,2,2,3,3.  If I reloaded the page 10X I got 10 of each without any additional 'serial port open' reports.  But your code works perfectly so I'll accept your answer while I try to wrap my head around why what I was doing was wrong.

Comment: I didn't see it in your example, but you did mention you were sending data to the serial port from the website. I think you serial device is storing the data coming from each website connection which is why the more you refresh, the more data you get back from the device.